# How to document the life cycle of products in the online store?

Tags: software-rec, website, documentation

I would like any way the documentation of the life cycle processes of products on the website. And in General, business process content, editing, etc. of the website.
For example.
I have a store offline that sells goods stock. The shares may be distributed on the online store. At the same time shares in the online store can be of two types: those that are an extension of conventional off-line on the online store, and which operate only in the online store.
Product should be taken into account this point and properly displayed.
I want to see in the result, for example, in the description of work with the product on the website:

1. The product is loaded in some way
2. Responsible for the description of the product that
3. The display uses such properties of the product
   depending on the category
4. Checks whether an item in promotions, if participate, then cheks types of shares etc ...
5. If the item is not in stock but arrived by a certain time, the product can be ordered
6. For a group of users of such goods is displayed in this way
7. The discount on the product is formed by so-and-so
   etc.

I would like to see such an extensive visual scheme where everything is reflected. Ideally, I could click on the diagram and see responsible, the conditions that lead to this point of the schema that the output that is fed to the input.
A very similar moment would be when using IDEF0, but for me it's not clearly, it is inconvenient, not user friendly. It is necessary that each Manager could click, for example, by user and see the details - how to contact him, how to send the mail, at what points it is in principle responsible, etc.
So this kind of "documentation" provided in a clear and convenient for each user to display any time in the life cycle of each entity of the online shop: goods, order, stock, news, etc.
Also it would be possible for individual users some software things to explain, for example, used to see a module or piece of code.
Is there something similar that you can expand and where you can keep such documentation?